# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException java.io.FileNotFoundException: bean.xml

Tags: java, spring

```
package com.cjc;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
    Student s1=context.getBean( "stu", Student.class);
    s1.m1();
    s1.m2();    }
}
```

after running program gives me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [D:\SpringProjects\SpringCJCclassPro2\bean.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: bean.xml
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:636)
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:142)
    at spring.context@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.cjc.Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: bean.xml
    at spring.core@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:179)
    at spring.beans@5.1.9.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably your *bean.xml* path isn't correct (indeed, the `Exception` thrown is : `D:\SpringProjects\SpringCJCclassPro2\bean.xml FileNotFoundException: bean.xml`)
Are you sure that it is the correct path? Where *bean.xml* is placed in your project?